# Use `defun` font-locking for other keywords

Tags: font-lock

I'm using the [`tco.el` package](https://github.com/Wilfred/tco.el), which provides tail-call optimisation for functions in elisp that call themselves in tail-position. The way such functions are identified is by using `defun-tco` instead of `defun`. But this means tail-call optimised functions no longer are styled like functions in terms of font-locking. How do I specify that `defun-tco` should be styled like `defun`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set font-lock keywords, e.g.,

```el
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("(\\(defun-tco\\)\\_>\\s *\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)?"
    (1 font-lock-keyword-face nil t)
    (2 font-lock-function-name-face nil t))))
```

the above is adapted from https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/8fe21b03/lisp/emacs-lisp/generator.el#L796. I suggest you to write an issue or pull request to the tco.el project, so you don't have to put the above to your own init file.

Comment: Thanks for this - I figured it was `font-lock-add-keywords`, but I couldn't find where `defun` was configured, so wasn't sure what the content should look like. Unfortunately, while the above correctly styles the `defun-tco` keyword itself and the following function name, it does not change the description's font-locking. I'm not sure where `defun`'s description font-locking is described.

Comment: @emacsomancer I don't think the color of `defun` is from font-lock keywords (i.e., searching via regexp, so it's slow). The core syntax highlighting is from syntactic parsing, see [(elisp) Font Lock Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html). I guess you mean docstring by "description", `defun-tco` doesn't support docstring at all, if it does, it will probably include `(declare (doc-string 3))` then you'll get the highlight out-of-box.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean the docstring. It looks like that is `font-lock-doc-face` is applied in `font-lock.el` by the function `font-lock-compile-keywords`. Unfortunately, it's not exactly clear how to hack that to get it to apply after `defun-tco` as well as `defun`. I wonder if there's a different way to approach this - to redefine how font-locking applies to `defun` so that it also applies to `defun-tco`, so that other font-locking could essential just be 'inherited'? [Edit: Ah, I see what you mean - docstring support simply isn't defined for `defun-tco`.]

Comment: @emacsomancer you only need to worry about `font-lock-function-name-face`. `defun-tco` is already colorized because it is defined as a macro. And if `defun-tco` supports docstring, the docstring will also be colorized because of `(declare (doc-string ...))`, the author will add it to follow the convention of defining macro.